# Regex to match everything in a string except "<br>", "<br />", "<br />"

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want a regex to match everything in a string except `"<br>", "<br />", "<br />".`

Reason being, i want to put string in a container and want "
" tags to execute and display other tags as they are written by the user.

For example: 
String-->

```
"I have <br> <br asked br>  <br />

a <br/> <h1>

<h1<br>>>>>>
<br>>>>>>>>  question  <b .  <a"
```

it should return :

```
"I have  <br asked br> 

    a <h1>

    <h1>>>>>
    >>>>>>>  question  <b .  <a"
```

I already have a regex to find all "br" tags which is `(<br\ ?\/?>)`. Just need a negation of the same.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: how about replacing your matches with empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the tags you mentioned and then replace it with an empty string.

```
<br\s*\/?>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pV9uH4/1)

To match all the `br` tags except the mentioned ones.

```
<br(?!\s*\/?>)[^>]*>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I want string excluding br tags. This regex just selects all br tags, which i've already done.

Comment: As Avinash told you, you just need to replace the matches by <code>""</code>

Comment: @Mahima: The solution above needs to be implemented on the result of your current regex. Using the expression and replacing with an empty string will purge all `<br />` tags from your input.